# Did Naruto REALLY fall in love with Hinata in The Last: Naruto the Movie?

Tags: naruto

So we know that throughout the whole Naruto series Hinata is **in love** with Naruto, and Naruto is oblivious to it. We also know that Naruto like Sakura, somehow. Later on two years after the war, Hinata is still in love with him.

## Spoiler below about The Last: Naruto the Movie

> Hinata, Naruto, Sakura, Sai, and Shikamaru are sent on a mission to rescue Hinata's sister. At one moment they had to go through something to get to this one place (sorry I can't recall what it was.) When they went through there they fell in a Genjutsu without knowing. In that Genjutsu Naruto is seeing a flashback of Hinata and him, but mostly Hinata. Naruto starts seeing some moments where Hinata as a kid wrote his name on a piece of paper and started to get happy, then after he fought Kiba she gave Naruto that healing cream, when he was on the ground when he was fighting Pain she protected him and confessed her love for him, Hinata talking to Sakura about Naruto, etc. After seeing all that, Sakura is able to break the Genjutsu on him and he is able to wake up. After that, they continue to look for Hinata's sister. Hinata and Naruto have to share one of Sai's painted birds to fly on. Naruto starts to look at Hinata different. Is it because he feels sorry for being oblivious of her love for him? Then after feeling sorry, did he start feeling something for her as well or what because after that guy (sorry I forgot his name) took Hinata with him, Naruto tried to get her back. He ended up losing and getting so hurt he kinda fell in a comma. After he woke up Sai and Shikamaru told him that Sakura was all awake day and night trying to bring him back and that he was saying Hinata's name over and over. He went to see Sakura because Shikamaru and Sai said she was really bad. When he was with her she said, "So you finally noticed", or something like that. Then at the end of the movie, he takes Hinata and starts blasting his Rasengan like that they can move faster. They end up really high in the sky, then he kisses her. When the credits are on we see that they got married, then after that, there is a short scene that shows her knitting a scarf and his training outside in the snow. A couple of seconds later their two kids are shown, then they all start a snow fight.

So my question is if Naruto did quickly fall in love with Hinata after the Genjutsu in the movie, or did he slowly start to feel something for her after it?

Also, in between that blank timeline of those two years, did Naruto figure out that Sakura was never going to fall in love with him and stopped liking her or did he stop liking her after being in that Genjutsu?

Comment: There are bits and pieces that hint at Naruto feeling the same for Hinata throughout the show. Like in the war, after Neji dies, Naruto holds Hinata's hand and tells her he managed to accomplish what he did so far because she was by his side.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is a [very good post](http://chennyyeo.tumblr.com/post/111771933631/my-analysisthoughts-about-the-last-naruto-the) by chennyyeo that may answer your question about *The Last - Naruto The Movie*.

Her theories and explanations

- proves that the movie does not contradict the manga (and it is actually a canon material) and
- to explain Naruto’s feelings (that he DID NOT fall for Hinata in the movie, rather, he **realized** his romantic feelings for her)

> Hinata as a kid wrote his (*Naruto*) name on a piece of paper and started to get happy

In this scene in the movie: (spoiler)

> ```
> '  Iruka Umino tells his students to write down the name of a 
>  person they would want to be with if the world was to end that day. Though 
>  Naruto tries to act tough towards Sakura Haruno, she ignores him for Sasuke. 
>  While Hinata is unsure who's name to write, she sees Naruto making a paper 
>  plane with his paper, which leads him to be scolded by Iruka. Naruto goes on 
>  to state that he has no friends nor family, and that the world isn't going to 
>  end. Seeing this, Hinata happily writes Naruto's name on her paper.'
> ```

To answer the question, Did Naruto **really** fall in love with Hinata
[chennyyeo][2] explained this as:

> Naruto turned 6-tails after Pain attacked Hinata. Hence, Hinata is the trigger of the transformation (as what Naruto confirmed in chapter. 490)
>
> Remember, when Gaara died, he just turned 2 tails. When Jiraiya and Kakashi died, he did not even transform. Antis may argue… “Maybe he transformed because of the shock that his friend attacked right in front of him” or “the seal is weakening”
>
> Hinata triggered **the worst feelings that Naruto ever felt**. Even though the seal is weak, it still needs enough force/level of rage for Naruto to transform.
>
> The situation clearly shows that Naruto have strong connection (love) for Hinata. Pain even said that love breeds hate. No, he’s not talking about Hinata’s feelings, he's talking about Naruto's. Pain assumed that the girl he attacked was special to Naruto. That’s why he said “*Do you hate me now?*”
>
> The movie guidebook also confirms this moment. “Naruto reads feeling of weakness reflected in Hinata’s eyes…. The two were connected so strongly that they could communicate in their eyes”
>
> In chapter 615, Naruto held Hinata’s hand. That only means one thing.
>
> **Naruto did all these romantic moments with Hinata subconsciously**.
>   He’s just stupid or dense that’s why he didn't know it was romantic love, and The Last movie explained this (that he cannot distinguish the difference between love of ramen and loving a person).

About your question here:

> So my question is if Naruto did quickly fall in love with Hinata after the Genjutsu in the movie or did he slowly start to feel something for her after it.

And to much elaborate the Movie

> > One of the many complains in the movie is the pacing. For just a day or so… the relationship between Naruto and Hinata changed. Let’s look
> >     closely.
>
> Mission timeline: Day 1: The team goes to a snowy place, goes to the
>   genjutsu lake, Toneri ask Hinata’s hand, Naruto became bashful,
>   and Naruto saw Hinata knitting the scarf.
>
> Day 2: Naruto did not wear Kushina’s scarf, Naruto and Hinata
>   flirting, Otsutsuki monument, and Hinata request Naruto to leave her alone
>   for a moment.
>
> Day 3: Hinata tries to stay away from Naruto, then in the night Naruto
>   confessed, then Hinata goes to Toneri.
>
> Yes… Within 3 days… I want to focus on day 1 and 2. This is when
>   Naruto knows his own feelings.
>
> So quickly, he acted different towards Hinata. What reason? The answer
>   is of course love.
>
> But is it possible to fall in love within days? The answer is, no.
>   Because love is not an instant thing.
>
> Does that mean the relationship between Naruto and Hinata is forced in the
>   movie? No. Why? Because Naruto did **not** fall for Hinata in the movie.
>   **he just realized he loved** HER ALL ALONG.
>
> Remember, he did not know the meaning of loving someone until the
>   Genjutsu trap. This gave him a context of Hinata’s feelings. After
>   that, he examined his own feeling. Actually, this is elaborated in the
>   last light novel.
>
> Thanks animecontinuum for the translation:
>
> > “So if that is a Genjutsu… Then, what are those things I saw about
> >      Hinata? Were all those part of my memories? No, I don’t think those
> >      are just ordinary memories. It’s more like my dreams and memories were
> >     mixed together. And so about Hinata, does that mean that I also…”
> >     Naruto blushed involuntarily and for an instant, he looked at Hinata.
>
> Clearly, the trap does not forced Naruto to love Hinata.
>
> It just triggered something within Naruto’s heart.
>
> Just think about it. When a person confessed to you. You would not fall
>   for him/her instantly. Unless, you also have feelings for him/her all
>   along.
>
> And another thing… Why do you thing Sakura encourage Hinata in the
>   first place. If she thinks that Hinata will just get rejected? (as
>   what UgamyRain said before)
>
> While Naruto was unconscious and Sakura’s healing him.. She said “you
>   finally got it. Blockhead” (cause Naruto repeatedly said “Hinata”)
>
> This only means one thing: Sakura knew that Naruto loved Hinata all
>   along.
>
> Sakura’s statement not only meant that Naruto finally understands
>   Hinata’s feelings. Also, he understands **his own feelings**. (Actually, the
>   latter is more appropriate because of the context of the scene.
>   Remember, Naruto kept repeating Hinata’s name, before Sakura said he
>   finally got it)
>
> When/how did Naruto fall for Hinata? Well it is in the manga. I
>   already explained that.
>
> Conclusion: the movie does not contradict the manga. It actually
>   supported our theory before: Naruto had feelings for Hinata all along.

Also In the last part of your question...

> Did Naruto figure out that Sakura was never going to fall in love with him and stopped liking her or did he stop liking her after being in that Genjutsu.

In "Naruto: the Last" there's a scene where Sakura explains this to Naruto. Sakura also helped Naruto to understand that he actually loves Hinata , not her.

Comment: Thanks for the very well-built, backed-by-evidence and generally detailed answer.
When was the scene with Saukra healing Naruto that you're referring to, and in what media is it (in Shippuden? In the movie)?

Answer (score 5):

Naruto didn't fall in love with Hinata in the movie, he was actually already in love with her. He just didn't know it was "love" since he's dumb. He always thought that loving ramen and loving a person was the same thing, so he never really thought much about it.

When Naruto saw the flashbacks, he realised he was in love with Hinata and learned loving food is different from loving a person.

He never really "loved" Sakura, he only liked her because she was pretty.

Answer (score 1):

In Naruto Shippuden, when Naruto is fighting Pain, Naruto sees Hinata coming and Hinata sees that Naruto can't move so she fights Pain, but he wins. Before that, Hinata tells Naruto she loves him, but Naruto already knew since they were kids. He used to look at Hinata sometimes, and he knew she felt something for him.

In The Last: Naruto the Movie, Naruto told Hinata he loved her, but truly he had feelings for her. Then he kissed her, he did fall in love together forever and lived happily ever after.

Answer (score 0):

He didn't fall in love with Hinata during the movie, but instead he fell in love with her throughout his whole life! He just realized he was in love in the movie.

Answer (score 0):

Naruto didn't fall in love with Hinata in The Last: Naruto the Movie. Naruto is in love with Hinata throughout the whole story of Naruto, he's so stupid he didn't realized it as "love" since those flashbacks happened in their mission in the movie. Started when Hinata was saved by Naruto since they were young it started there. I can't tell if it was Naruto being dense back then, or he just can't tell what really is love, well he is stupid. Relating this to his confession to Sakura when they were on the Iron Land, that confession was to at least waver Sakura's eagerness to follow and rescue Sasuke since it was dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

Whether or not a character in a given story universe "REALLY" had a change of emotional feelings in any direction, is something only the writer/creator knows, unless specifically stated otherwise in print, in words that cannot be misinterpreted.

Aside from that situation, we as viewers have to go on our feelings and views on the development of the character over time, in order to make what amounts to an educated guess of their true feelings.  And this goes for books/manga/life/anime/live action.

My belief is this:  When you have love for one person, that never really dies, even if said love is unrequited.  So in the case with Hinata, he may truly love her, but he likely still loves *cough* other girl too.

Answer (score 0):

I think he was in love with her all along. Starting with their childhood, in the academy, and in the chunin exams. That love was so obvious. He swore with her blood that he was going to win, and he did.

Also, in episode 151, in the original Naruto series, the mission with Hinata, Kiba, and Chino, when the Hidden Stone shinobi abducted Hinata, Naruto was so nervous he even showed Kurama's eyes, and one of the kidnappers said that she might be his girlfriend.

In the Pain arc. this love of Naruto's was like the sun. He was going to transform completely into the Nine Tails. but his father came and renew the seal again.

In the war arc., we saw that one of Naruto's clones can see and read Hinata's eyes.

Naruto: The Last was evidence that Naruto has always loved Hinata. In the Genjutsu lake, Naruto went to the deep of his heart and brought back all the memories of Hinata. Why specially Hinata? Sai said that he was dreaming about his brother. We already knew he was precious to him. The same goes for Naruto. This movie is also an evidence that Naruto is really dumb who can not make the difference between loving a person and food.

The last thing I would like to say is that these two have a very very very special sort of love. They are the best.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to Naruto and Hinata, he loved her, but because of the fact that he had no parents, he couldn't understand his feelings for her because he had never seen people interact like that before (his parents did all the time, but died while he was only an infant so he never got to learn from them).

In *The Last* the Genjutsu only helped Naruto see his own feelings towards Hinata, and realized she had acknowledged him and cared for him more than anyone else ever had. His denseness is a result of never knowing or experiencing it first hand.